# Houdini, Python: range, randomize and timeshift keyframes

Tags: python, houdini

I have a simple model `object_A` that has `10 keyframes`.
Frames 1-5 have rotation only on X, frames 6-10 have rotation only on Y.

Per `copy to point` (Houdini) I copy `object_A` as an `instance` on every point on a grid.

Now I would like to `range, randomize and timeshift` the keyframes for each instance.
In a `range` from 1-5, chose a `random` key and `timeshift` that keyframe to `frame 1`.

I also want to define the keyframes in a dropdown list.
The dropdown has two tokens and two labels `((1, 5), (rotation_x))` and `((6, 10), (rotation_y))`

My first lines look like that:

```
import random

def retime_frames():

    # values from dropdown tokens
    fr_get = hou.evalParm('choose_frame_set')

    for frX in range(fr_get):
        fRandom = (random.choice(frX))
        hou.parm('retime_frame').set(str(fRandom))
        print fRandom
```

I get an error that way and dont know where.
If I use a list like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] it works.
But as soon as I try to use range(var) it does not work anymore.

```
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the random frames.

```
import random

""" Give out randomized, single frame
from given frame sequence preset. To add more presets
modify 'Choose Frame Set' menu in parameters.
'token' example1: '1-5' = frames 1 till 5.
'token' example2: '1-3, 7, 10-12' = 1 till 3 + 7 + 10 till 12
"""

def retime_frames():

    fr_range = hou.evalParm("choose_frame_set")
    fr_sequence = []

    for frames in fr_range.split(','):
        if '-' in frames:
            a, b = frames.split('-')
            a, b = int(a), int(b)
            fr_sequence.extend(range(a, b + 1))
        else:
            a = int(part)

    # random frame from frame_sequence, stepping (frame_range, step)
    random_frame = random.sample(fr_sequence, 1)

    hou.parm('retime_frame').set(str(random_frame)[1])
    print str(random_frame)[1]
```

[image: retime_frames]